# String was Not recognised as valid date time C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a web app which is working fine on `localhost` but when I uploaded the web app, I get an error on my calender

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
Line 1291: string strstartdate = "";  
Line 1292: strstartdate = txtfrmdate.Text;  
Line 1293: DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strstartdate);  
Line 1294: string strfstartdate = dt.ToString(strstartdate);  
Line 1295: DateTime dtnew = Convert.ToDateTime(strfstartdate);
```

It is working fine with the date range of (1/12), but when I choose date between (13/31), I get this error.

This is what is selected (`13-09-2016`)

My C# page

```
string strstartdate = "";
strstartdate = txtfrmdate.Text;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strstartdate);
string strfstartdate = dt.ToString(strstartdate);
DateTime dtnew = Convert.ToDateTime(strfstartdate);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("csuvdaterange");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();

SqlParameter[] param =
{
    new SqlParameter("@logintype",com.ToString()),
    new SqlParameter("@name",lblempname.Text),
    new SqlParameter("@datefrm",DateTime.ParseExact(txtfrmdate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
    new SqlParameter("@dateto",DateTime.ParseExact(txttodate.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
};
```

Comment: you to should validate date textbox for the input date format so that you can parse the date using DateTime.ParseExact() method otherwise it will be a error prone code for exception

Comment: I am trying to make some sense of your code, but I give up. I can't understand what is the purpose of the first five lines.

Comment: @Steve ok sir the starting 5 lines are created when i was doing R&D but i don't need the anyway and the error is coming on that line, i just remove the starting 5 lines and waiting for my superior to return and upload the page again

Answer (score 3):

The [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) on the web server would appear to be US, and your text isn't in a format where month precedes the day - it's inferring a month of 13, which isn't a valid date.

You should parse the date the same way as your do later in your code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtfrmdate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Convert.ToDateTime

Answer (score 0):

in order to avoid system from confusion on different regional date format settings I recommend that date format be always mentioned while converting types...